# Use Eddystone Beacon to Show notification in Android Status Bar

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, altbeacon, android-statusbar

I've been able to successfully create an app (thanks davidgyoung!) that monitors beacons in the background and then subsequently opens the app in the background.

Now I would like my app to first prompt with a notification in the status bar saying something like "I've detected a beacon! Would you like to open out app?". Then the user would click on the notification to open the app or dismiss it and ignore the notification.

I've searched on stack overflow for something like but haven't had much success in finding something relevant to beacons. I did find this page that talks about adding `StatusBar` notifications but I'm not having much success.

Particularly its in my `BeaconReferenceApplication.java` and `MonitoringActivity.java` file. I think I put the code in the correct place (after `didEnterRegion`) but I have unresolved classes for areas like `notificationButton`, `setLatestEventInfo`, etc. Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

BeaconReferenceApplication.java:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;

public class BeaconReferenceApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = "BeaconReferenceApp";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
    private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
    private MonitoringActivity monitoringActivity = null;


    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        // By default the AndroidBeaconLibrary will only find AltBeacons.  If you wish to make it
        // find a different type of beacon, you must specify the byte layout for that beacon's
        // advertisement with a line like below.  The example shows how to find a beacon with the
        // same byte layout as AltBeacon but with a beaconTypeCode of 0xaabb.  To find the proper
        // layout expression for other beacon types, do a web search for "setBeaconLayout"
        // including the quotes.
        //
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));

        Log.d(TAG, "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving");
        // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
        Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion", Identifier.parse("2F234454F4911BA9FFA6"), null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

        // simply constructing this class and holding a reference to it in your custom Application
        // class will automatically cause the BeaconLibrary to save battery whenever the application
        // is not visible.  This reduces bluetooth power usage by about 60%
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

        // If you wish to test beacon detection in the Android Emulator, you can use code like this:
        // BeaconManager.setBeaconSimulator(new TimedBeaconSimulator() );
        // ((TimedBeaconSimulator) BeaconManager.getBeaconSimulator()).createTimedSimulatedBeacons();
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user whenever a Beacon
        // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.
        Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
        if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "sending notification to StatusBar");
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage) {
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Notification notification = new Notification(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        "New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());

                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                        notificationIntent, 0);

                notification.setLatestEventInfo(MonitoringActivity.this, notificationTitle,
                        notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
                notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
            }

        }
        } else {
            if (monitoringActivity != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "auto launching MainActivity");

                // The very first time since boot that we detect an beacon, we launch the
                // MainActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                // Important:  make sure to add android:launchMode="singleInstance" in the manifest
                // to keep multiple copies of this activity from getting created if the user has
                // already manually launched the app.
                this.startActivity(intent);
                haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = true;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        if (monitoringActivity != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"I no longer see a beacon.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        if (monitoringActivity != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " + state);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("Beacon Reference Application")
                        .setContentText("An beacon is nearby.")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class));
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }

    public void setMonitoringActivity(MonitoringActivity activity) {
        this.monitoringActivity = activity;
    }

}
```

MonitoringActivity.java:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;

public class MonitoringActivity extends Activity  {
    protected static final String TAG = "MonitoringActivity";
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;

    private WebView mWebView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_monitoring);

        // code for button notification
        Button notificationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notificationButton);

        notificationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Notify("Title: Meeting with Business",
                        "Msg:Pittsburg 10:00 AM EST ");
            }
        });

        // code for button notification

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://communionchapelefca.org/edy-home");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        verifyBluetooth();
        Log.d(TAG, "Application just launched");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // Android M Permission check
            if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("This app needs location access");
                builder.setMessage("Please grant location access so this app can detect beacons in the background.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                    @TargetApi(23)
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                                PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
                    }

                });
                builder.show();
            }
        }
    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url)
        {
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "coarse location permission granted");
                } else {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("Functionality limited");
                    builder.setMessage("Since location access has not been granted, this app will not be able to discover beacons when in the background.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        }

                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onRangingClicked(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, RangingActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((BeaconReferenceApplication) this.getApplicationContext()).setMonitoringActivity(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        ((BeaconReferenceApplication) this.getApplicationContext()).setMonitoringActivity(null);
    }

    private void verifyBluetooth() {

        try {
            if (!BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this).checkAvailability()) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("Bluetooth not enabled");
                builder.setMessage("Please enable bluetooth in settings and restart this application.");
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        finish();
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            }
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Bluetooth LE not available");
            builder.setMessage("Sorry, this device does not support Bluetooth LE.");
            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
            builder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            });
            builder.show();

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Hi friend, This code put in didEnterRegion is correct, But you have to has list contain beacon has added. Because didEnterRegion  when callback return only 1 device. -> So check if not exist in list -> show notification

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix my problem by using the example from the [Android Developers website for Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). I used their sample code, adapted it to my use, and then even further used .bigText to make my notification look great. Credit goes to them and daviggyoung for getting my app working. Thanks!

I also didnt need to edit my MonitoringActivity.java like I posted earlier.

final BeaconReferenceApplication.java:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Region;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.powersave.BackgroundPowerSaver;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.RegionBootstrap;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.BootstrapNotifier;

public class BeaconReferenceApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = "BeaconReferenceApp";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;
    private BackgroundPowerSaver backgroundPowerSaver;
    private boolean haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot = false;
    private MonitoringActivity monitoringActivity = null;


    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        // By default the AndroidBeaconLibrary will only find AltBeacons.  If you wish to make it
        // find a different type of beacon, you must specify the byte layout for that beacon's
        // advertisement with a line like below.  The example shows how to find a beacon with the
        // same byte layout as AltBeacon but with a beaconTypeCode of 0xaabb.  To find the proper
        // layout expression for other beacon types, do a web search for "setBeaconLayout"
        // including the quotes.
        //
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=00,p:3-3:-41,i:4-13,i:14-19"));

        Log.d(TAG, "setting up background monitoring for beacons and power saving");
        // wake up the app when a beacon is seen
        Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion", Identifier.parse("2F234454F4911BA9FFA6"), null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);

        // simply constructing this class and holding a reference to it in your custom Application
        // class will automatically cause the BeaconLibrary to save battery whenever the application
        // is not visible.  This reduces bluetooth power usage by about 60%
        backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);

        // If you wish to test beacon detection in the Android Emulator, you can use code like this:
        // BeaconManager.setBeaconSimulator(new TimedBeaconSimulator() );
        // ((TimedBeaconSimulator) BeaconManager.getBeaconSimulator()).createTimedSimulatedBeacons();
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        // In this example, this class sends a notification to the user whenever a Beacon
        // matching a Region (defined above) are first seen.
        Log.d(TAG, "did enter region.");
        if (!haveDetectedBeaconsSinceBoot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "sending notification to StatusBar");
            //begin code for notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                            .setContentTitle("Message from Communion Chapel")
                            .setContentText("Welcome! Thanks for coming!")
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText("We noticed that you're here today, click here to open the app and get today's Sermon Notes and Bulletin."))
                            .setAutoCancel(true);
            ;

// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class);

// The stack builder object will contain an artificial back stack for the
// started Activity.
// This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of
// your application to the Home screen.
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MonitoringActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                            0,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify(123, mBuilder.build());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        if (monitoringActivity != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"I no longer see a beacon.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
        if (monitoringActivity != null) {
            Log.d(TAG,"I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: " + state);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("Beacon Reference Application")
                        .setContentText("A beacon is nearby.")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class));
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }

    public void setMonitoringActivity(MonitoringActivity activity) {
        this.monitoringActivity = activity;
    }

}
```